# MacVim, how can i read the content of `version` into the edit area?

Tags: vim

i know that i can check the vim version by `:version` in normal mode

but what the command give me is a read-only text, i can not search anything and that's a lot of text

so how can I read from the `:version` command's result into the edit area?

i think maybe it's something like `:r!ls` but how?

btw, i don't think `:r!vim --version` is the correct way to do this, cause something the vim with GUI is not the same one in terminal.

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command [`:redir`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3aredir) redirects messages into a file, a register, or a variable.

You can redirect `:version` output into a register, say `"x`, and insert the register contents into your buffer, either by using a normal mode command `"xp` or an Ex command `:put x`.

```
:redir @x | silent version | redir END
:put x
```

This works for all messages, not just for `:version`.

Comment: Oh crap, I know I shouldn't make a coffee for my wife in the middle of answering a question.

Comment: @romainl Heh, luckily *my* coffee was already sitting right in front of me ...!

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply interested in getting the version information out of Vim, then you can get it with the command line option [`--version`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#--version) as well.

```
$ vim --version > version.txt
```

Specifically for MacVim you need to be careful that you invoke the right Vim program. That is, *not* the system Vim but the MacVim executable. Try:

```
$ mvim --version > version.txt
```

Now `version.txt` contains the version information, which is identical with `:version` output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:redir` command to place the output of `:version` in a register:

```
:redir @x
:version
:redir END

(or :redir @x | version | redir END in one line)
```

then paste it in your buffer:

```
"xp
```

Since you are using MacVim, I assume that the `mvim` script is correctly installed somewhere in your `$PATH`. If that's the case, you can also do:

```
:r !mvim --version
```